# gmod adjust player health on func_button

Tags: hammer, garrys-mod

Because I spent so long figuring this out, here is a post for it.

I want to make a relative adjustment to the player who presses a button's health.

I have two brushs, tied to two separate "func_button" entities and would like to, on pressing one button add  a relative amount of health to the player who pressed the button, say +/-15 hitpoints; and on pressing the other button, remove 15 health simmialrly.

Futhermore, i would like to modify the player health by a relative amount when they use a physics prop.

things that dont seem to work

- onButtonPushed !activator AddHealth: AddHealth broken for players
- onButtonPushed !activator RemoveHealth: RemoveHealth broken for players
- onPlayerUse !activator SetHealth: activator is broken

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me finally

gmod specific,
add a new entity, lets say its target name is "healthpot", of class "lua_run", give it a code edict value like

```
ACTIVATOR:SetHealth(math.Clamp(ACTIVATOR:Health()+15, 0, ACTIVATOR:GetMaxHealth()))
```

for the heal func_button, OnButtonPressed, healthpod, RunCode

---

this button can be parented to a physics_prop, and the code calue can be made to subtract rather than add as needed.